# OneWayToSource binding resetting target value

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Why is the OneWayToSource binding resetting my target value?
Here is the binding code:

```
SolidColorBrush brush = GetTemplateChild("PART_PreviewBrush") as SolidColorBrush;
            if (brush != null)
            {
                Binding binding = new Binding("Color");
                binding.Source = brush;
                binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource;
                this.SetBinding(ColorPicker.ColorProperty, binding);
            }
```

I set the "Color" dependency property in xaml. But it gets overwritten by the binding. After that the binding works ok. 
So, essentially my problem is: I can't give a starting value to the "Color" property because it gets overwritten by the binding.

EDIT:

I made a workaround that solves the problem, but still don't understand why OneWayToSource behaves like that:

```
System.Windows.Media.Color CurrentColor = this.Color;
                this.SetBinding(ColorPicker.ColorProperty, binding);
                this.Color = CurrentColor;
```

EDIT 2:

Found a possible solution:
I have to set:

```
binding.FallbackValue = this.Color;
```

Comment: Couldn't you just bind the other way round? Something like `brush.SetBinding(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, new Binding("Color") { Source = this });`

Comment: @Clemens: SolidColorBrush does not have SetBinding, that is why I have to go with OneWayToSource.

Comment: You might also want to read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4875751/1136211).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [BindingOperations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.aspx) class to set the binding:

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(
    brush, SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, new Binding("Color") { Source = this });
```

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. That's the best way to do without OneWayToSource. But I cant mark this as the answer because I want to figure out OneWayToSource.