# Binding A UserControl DependencyProperty, Always DefaultValue?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I've got a UserControl with a DependencyProperty created in its CodeBehind:

```
public partial class PanelMap_Control : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<GMapMarker> Markers
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<GMapMarker>)GetValue(MarkersProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MarkersProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MarkersProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Markers", typeof(ObservableCollection<GMapMarker>), typeof(PanelMap_Control), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Inside the UserControl is a Map, which contains the original collection of markers (not a DependencyProperty).  I need to make this available for binding outside the UserControl, so at the end of the constructor (once the map's Markers are all setup), I set it to the control's DependencyProperty:

```
    public PanelMap_Control()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //...map setup...
        this.Markers = _map.Markers;
    }
```

Then, users of the UserControl can bind like:

```
    <local:PanelMap_Control Markers="{Binding Path=MapMarkers, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
```

Where in the ViewModel:

```
    public ObservableCollection<GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation.GMapMarker> MapMarkers
    {
        private get
        {
            return _mapMarkers; 
        }
        set 
        {
            _mapMarkers = value; 
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation.GMapMarker> _mapMarkers;
```

The problem is, the ViewModel's MapMarkers property always ends up with the default value "null."  I tried setting breakpoints on the SetValue call in PanelMap_Control and the ViewModel property's setter.  The debugger first hits SetValue(), at which point _map.Markers is valid (non-null).  THEN it hits the ViewModel's setter, with a value of null - and never reflects the actual valid object I pass to SetValue().

I'm sure I'm just missing something simple, but I can't for the life of me figure out why SetValue(non-null) would be *followed by* ViewModel.MapMarkers.set(null)...and never again.

(Side note 1: I realize this DependencyProperty won't work for TwoWay binding - i.e. I can't update _map.Markers in the UserControl. That's fine, I only need to read from it externally.)

(Side note 2: The _map.Markers object will never be changed - only the items in the collection - so setting the DependencyProperty to the initial collection should be sufficient.)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16286284/1136211) may give you an explanation. The debugger doesn't break at a second SetValue call with a null value (when the Binding is established) because WPF bypasses the property setter and directly calls SetValue when a property is set in XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the following questions.

[OneWayToSource Binding seems broken in .NET 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875751/onewaytosource-binding-seems-broken-in-net-4-0)

[OneWayToSource binding resetting target value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772749/onewaytosource-binding-resetting-target-value)

`OneWayToSource` does actually reset the target property (Markers) initially. This is by design. There is more information about this on the links above.

As a workaround you could try to set up the binding programmatically:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var vm = new ViewModel();
    DataContext = vm;
    vm.MapMarkers = control.Markers;
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(control, PanelMap_Control.MarkersProperty, new Binding("MapMarkets") { TargetNullValue = control.Markers, FallbackValue = control.Markers });
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<local:PanelMap_Control x:Name="control" />
```